# Lazy loaded Angular modules interfere although paths are completely different

Tags: angular, routes, url-routing

I'm trying to have different modules that are lazy loaded but for some reason `/members` overrides the `/groups` path, meaning I cannot see the GroupListComponent when visiting `/groups`, I see the MemberListComponent instead.

I cannot see what it is causing it to do this because in fact they should be totally different paths.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'groups', loadChildren: () => import('./../group/group.module').then(m => m.GroupModule) },
  { path: 'members', loadChildren: () => import('./../shared/modules/member/member.module').then(m => m.MemberModule) },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/groups', pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
...
```

**group-routing.module.ts**

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: GroupListComponent },
  { path: ':groupid', component: GroupDetailedComponent },
  { path: ':groupid/members', component: MemberListComponent },
  { path: ':groupid/members/:memberid', component: MemberDetailedComponent },
];
...
```

**member-routing.module.ts**

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MemberListComponent },
  { path: ':memberid', component: MemberDetailedComponent }
];
...
```

**A bypass, but not really a solution**
If I were to change the `member-routing.module.ts` to

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'all', component: MemberListComponent },
  { path: ':memberid', component: MemberDetailedComponent }
];
...
```

then it's no longer a problem, but for a sake of site consistency I don't want to have `/groups` for a listing of all groups and `/members/all` for a listing of all members.

**Extra information that might be relevant**

GroupModule imports MemberModule for the sake of having URLs such as `/groups/:groupid/members`, but maybe that causes MembersModuleRouting to override the GroupsModuleRouting since it is loaded when GroupsModule is loaded, but even so.

Answer (score 0):

After a good night of sleep, I came back to this issue and it became clear that I had to load the `MemberModule` once more in the `GroupRoutingModule`. So I only had to change 2 lines of code to fix this issue.

**changed group-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: GroupListComponent },
  { path: ':groupid', component: GroupDetailedComponent },
  { path: ':groupid/members', loadChildren: () => import('./../shared/modules/member/member.module').then(m => m.MemberModule) },
];
```